# Change input value with React Rudux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux

I'm using react redux to create a CRUD to learn react.
But I can't change the input value with react redux.

Here is my *form.js*

```
class UsuarioForm extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="animated fadeIn">
                <Row>
                    <Col xs="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="name">Nome</Label>
                            <Input type="text" id="nome" value={this.props.usuario.Nome} placeholder="Informe o nome" />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs="12">
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label htmlFor="ccnumber">Usuário</Label>
                            <Input type="text" id="ccnumber" value={this.props.usuario.Login} placeholder="Informe o login" required />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                </Row>

                <Button type="submit" size="sm" color="primary">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check" /> Gravar
                </Button>
                <Button type="button" size="sm" color="danger" onClick={this.voltar.bind(this)}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="arrow-left" /> Voltar
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { usuario: state.usuarioFormReducer };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        busca: (id) => {
            dispatch(UsuarioService.busca(id));
        }
    }
}

const UsuarioFormContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsuarioForm);

export default UsuarioFormContainer;
```

How to make this? I need use the reducer to change? I need use the state of react?

Comment: Can you please format your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a setName function and add it in input on every keypress

**action.js**

```
export const setName = (value) => ({
  type: 'SET_NAME',
  payload: value
})
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  Nome: '',
  Login: '',
}
export function usuarioFormReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NAME:
        return {
            ...state,
            Nome: action.payload,
        };
 }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: It is not a good practice to save form info. on store level instead of state level.

Comment: but dont use redux, i need with redux